# Using a Perl module in my own directory

Tags: perl, module

I'm trying to download a module from CPAN and save it into the same directory as the directory that my Perl script is in because I don't have permissions to download it normally, but when I try to run the code, it can't find the script.

My Code:

```
#usr/bin/perl
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
```

Error Message:

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm in @INC at temp.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at temp.pl line 3.
```

How can I tell Perl where to look for the module? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "download it normally"?

Comment: I tried using the FindBin method, but now it says
Can't locate FindBin.pm in @INC at temp.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at temp.pl line 3.
How do I solve this?

Comment: @Andrew FindBin is a core module, so it should already be installed somewhere in `@INC`. What are the contents of `@INC` in the error message?